# substitute <br />for a comma using python & beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[image]

Html line of code is as above.

I've managed to get it from [this url](https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city%20of%20edinburgh%2C%20BOSWALL%20PARKWAY%2C%20EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET%20DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL%20PARKWAY%2C%20EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL%20PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&ST=&SEARCH_TERM=city+of+edinburgh%2C+BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&ASSESSOR_ID=&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=BOSWALL+PARKWAY%2C+EDINBURGH&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=BOSWALL+PARKWAY&UARN=110B60329&PPRN=000000000001745&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL#results'

baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)

# content of search page in soup 
html = soup(response.content,"lxml")

Address = LeftBlockData[3].get_text().strip()
print (Address)
```

However it prints like this `'29 BOSWALL PARKWAYEDINBURGHEH5 2BR'`

where there is is `<br />` between text its replaced with a `'no space'`.

I would like to put a comma in where there is currently a `<br />`.

Can anyone kindly suggest a method please?

Comment: sure, have added more of code thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set your separator when getting the text of the node.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """<td rowspan="1">29 BOSWALL PARKWAY<br />EDINBURGH<br />EHS 2BR</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, "xml")

print(soup.find("td").get_text(strip=True, separator=','))
```

Outputs:

> 29 BOSWALL PARKWAY,EDINBURGH,EHS 2BR

Comment: Once again thank you zroq, In 2nd last line of my code a above i put     Address = LeftBlockData[3].get_text(strip=True, separator=',') and it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<td rowspan="1">29 BOSWALL PARKWAY<br />EDINBURGH<br />EHS 2BR</td>')
text_list = soup.td.contents
text_you_want = '{}, {}, {}'.format(text_list[0], text_list[2], text_list[4])

// similarly

text_you_want = ", ".join([item for item in text_list if isinstance(item, str)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of to possible ways:

1. Use `.get_text(separator=" ")`. The parts will be separated by a space instead.
2. In BeautifulSoup4, you can use [strings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings). `" ".join(LeftBlockData[3].strings)`